# How to test which which objective is greatest?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to to test which player objective score is the highest, then return the result.

I thought that

```
/scoreboard players operation playerName obj1 > playerName obj2
```

running on a clock would give a signal only when obj1 was greater than obj2, but it just changes the value that's highest or something like that that I don't understand.

So how do I check if one objective is higher than the other? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
/scoreboard players operation selector1 obj1 > selector2 obj2
```

`selector1` will have their score set equal to the highest `obj2` score found from all targets obtained from `selector2`, as long as that resulting score is not higher than the `obj1` score of `selector1`. Given the following playerscores for obj2:

1. PlayerA: 3
2. PlayerB: 5
3. PlayerC: 8
4. PlayerD: 8

`selector1` will have their `obj1` score set equal to the highest value from the obtained targets, in this case being 8 from both `PlayerC` and `PlayerD`. However, if `selector1` had an `obj1` score higher than that maximum, their score will remain unchanged. If their score was 9, then it will remain 9. All targets from `selector2` will not have their scores changed (unless, of course, `selector1` was part of the selected targets from `selector2`).

If you're looking to say the name of the target who had that highest score, such as for high score tracking, then you can create a secondary objective to store a copy of the initial scores and then subtract the highest score (obtained via > operator) from the copied scores. Any players with a remaining score of 0 would be the highest-scoring players.

**Prerequisites:**

Objective to hold the initial scores.

```
/scoreboard objectives add SCORE dummy
```

Objective to hold a copy of the scores.

```
/scoreboard objectives add TSCORE dummy
```

**Detection:**

The following must be run in numerical order on a clock. This is assuming the end of a round/game where `SCORE` is already populated.

1. First, copy their initial scores.

   ```
   /execute @a ~ ~ ~ scoreboard players operation @a[c=1] TSCORE = @a[c=1] SCORE
   ```
2. Next, set fake player `#HIGHEST` to have the highest score from `SCORE` among players.

   ```
   /scoreboard players operation #HIGHEST SCORE > @a SCORE
   ```
3. Subtract all player's `TSCORE` by the `SCORE` score of `#HIGHEST`.

   ```
   /scoreboard players operation @a TSCORE -= #HIGHEST SCORE
   ```
4. Finally, any players with a remaining `TSCORE` of 0 will be those that had the highest score. You can announce their names via `/tellraw`.

   ```
   /tellraw @a [{"selector":"@a[score_TSCORE_min=0]"}," had the highest score!"]
   ```

Comment: I currently don't have another player to test this on, so I'll try later. Even though this is ultimately what I was going for, is it possible to check two different objectives on 1 player?

Comment: You can also use non-player entities for testing. For two different objectives, you'll need two separate commands: `/scoreboard players operation player1 high > player1 obj1` and `/scoreboard players operation player1 high > player1 obj2`. Their `high` score will be set to whichever objective was highest. To determine which objective that was, you'd create a copy of the scores and subtract `high` from them, and whichever was 0 was the higher objective (same concept as above).